# Como consigo criar uma imagem no docker mas ao invez de utilizar o copy para os arquivos usar clone do git

Tags: github, docker

Tenho um repositorio no github com meu projeto e preciso criar uma imagem pra rodar esse projeto mas não estou conseguindo

```
FROM python:3.6.7
MAINTAINER RENAN SACCA
CMD ["git","clone","https://github.com/Renan-Sacca/teste-docker.git"]
WORKDIR teste-docker
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

Ele da erro na hora de instalar o requisito fala que não encontrou então acho q o problema esta em pegar diretorio do git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está na confusão entre `CMD` e `RUN`.

Segundo a documentação do Docker, a instrução `CMD` serve prioritariamente para indicar os parametros a serem usados pelo entrypoint de um container. E adiciona que o Dockerfile deve conter uma ÚNICA instrução `CMD` e caso mais de uma seja adicionada, somente a última terá efeito.

Este é justamente o problema do seu Dockerfile. Primeiro que, mesmo que `CMD ["git","clone","https://github.com/Renan-Sacca/teste-docker.git"]` estivesse correto, seria ignorado porque há outro `CMD`. Ainda que não existisse outro, o `CMD` é utilizado somente no momento da inicialização do container. É por isso que ao fazer `RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt` não existe o `requirements.txt`.

Para se executar instruções no build de uma imagem deve-se usar o `RUN`. Dessa forma, o seu Dockerfile deveria ser algo como

```
FROM python:3.6.7
LABEL maintainer="RENAN SACCA"
EXPOSE 8000

RUN git clone https://github.com/Renan-Sacca/teste-docker.git
WORKDIR teste-docker
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

---

Obs:

- a instrução `MAINTAINER` está obsoleta e foi substituída por `LABEL`;
- a instrução `EXPOSE` foi movida a fim de melhorar a legibilidade do código;

Comment: Entendi, estou aprendendo meio do zero então não sabia disso do cmd, testei o codigo que deixou e funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda